# Derivation of gradient of SSE in Geodesic Regression

Tags: st.statistics, riemannian-geometry, linear-programming, linear-regression, geodesics

On page 79 (or page 5) of this [this paper](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww-sop.inria.fr%2Fasclepios%2Fevents%2FMFCA11%2FProceedings%2FMFCA11_3_1&ei=O-wIVbv0LYHZggTzvQM&usg=AFQjCNEp9Q4TMuDE9LgJoL7KkMvYQwlROg&sig2=mjetJWb7_lXBRNCd51eGag&bvm=bv.88198703,d.eXY) the gradient of the SSE of the Geodesic model is described explicitly.  My question is how are these equitations derived in detail; where can I find the computations?

Moreover, if I wanted to solve a contained version of this equation how would can I modify the final solution based on my constraints?

Comment: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpa.3160300502/pdf

Comment: there you can find the computation of the gradient of the squared distance function.

Comment: Thanks :), but is there another reference I cannot seem to get access to this article...

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I got access by my university. The article is called 'riemannian center of mass and mollifier smoothing' by H. Karcher. I'm not sure if this article is available for free

Comment: Also why does he derive the adjoint of Exp instead Exp itself?